# Draw the edges of a graph using only perpendicular lines

Tags: graph-theory

Let us assume that I have a set of vertices ${V}$.  These vertices belong to a graph that is not necessarily planar.  These vertices reside at known $(x,y)$ locations in the xy plane.  What might an algorithm be for drawing the edges using only perpendicular lines in such a way that the total number of intersections of the edges is minimized?

The graph is not necessarily planar, so intersections may be unavoidable even if the perpendicularity constraint is removed.

Comment: You might want to do a search on orthogonal routing algorithms.  There should be extensive literature due to the importance of this problem in circuit design.

Comment: By the way, in the first sentence you say the graph is known to be planar, but in the last sentence it is not necessarily planar... So which is it?

Comment: Good catch, thanks. And thanks for the info. I knew it must be a thing that exists but didn't know it's name

Comment: See also : Planar straight-line graph and Near-planar graphs. Note that it's quite hard to find a minimal crossing for a non-planar graph.

Comment: In this problem, the vertices are fixed and the edges are free to shift around.  In a straight-line embedding the vertices are free but the edges are entirely determined, so it's kind of a dual to this problem.